# Speed up git add for large numbers of files and a filtered (clean=sha1sum) repository

Tags: git

I have a git repository with a filter in `.gitattributes` as `* filter=ls`, so that each file is filtered before stored in the repo. The filter is configured in `.git/config` like this:

```
[filter "ls"]
    clean = sha1sum
```

So, instead of checking in the actual files, only their `sha1sum` is stored. I'm tracking a very large number of files (~6 million) and, among them, there are many files with large size. (total size of the files is roughly 600GB).

I add a new directory to the repo like this, so the repo is always in a garbage collected and repacked state.

```
git add path/
git commit -m ...
git repack -a
git gc
git prune
```

For some reason, the `git add` takes vastly different times to complete. Running the above lines on two relatively similar folders with ~600k files and 10GB each can take 10 minutes for the first and 5 hours for the second folder. Is there any way I can speed up `git add` here?

Everything is on a local disc and sha1sum is not the bottle neck here.

---

Some background: I'm (ab)using git here to compare two different directories by checking both into their own git repo and comparing their git object tree representation via `git ls-files` and `git ls-tree`. I can't use something like `git lfs`.

Comment: To confirm that `sha1sum` is not the bottleneck : have you tried running `sha1sum` on each individual file of your disk to measure how long it takes ?

Comment: Something like `find thatdir/ -type f | xargs sha1sum`

Comment: Hi, I did, it took a few minutes to finish.

Comment: Ok. To have insights on git actions, you can set [env vars](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#_debugging) : try running `GIT_TRACE=1 git add path/` or `GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE=1 git add path/`, and inspect what parts take such a long time.